# Should we have a tag for word problems?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've noticed that a lot of puzzles that I've been posting (and a few others) are word problems. Does this merit a tag, compared to, say, questions about sudokus or Rubik's Cubes?

Comment: So I've got one for vote, and one somewhat half-hearted against vote. Since I take an especial interest to word problems on this site, I think I'll instate that tag.

Answer (score -1):

What unifies the Sudoku and Rubik's cube tags are common methodologies and algorithms, which serve as a helpful classification for questions. More specific tags can work to classify these problems.

I'm not sure word problems as a whole share this type of classification, however. While this would potentially be useful, I toss my vote in negative.

Just my two cents, though!

Answer (score -1):

I would vote that there could be a tag for [word-problems](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-problems).  I often use tags on SE sites to tell at a glance if a particular problem is one I'd be interested in looking at, and a [word-problems](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-problems) tag would help me with that.

Like [Emrakul](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/134/11), though, this is just my two cents.